# excluding files from flake8 by Python version

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x, flake8

I have a project that is Python 2 and 3 compatible, but I have some test cases that only run in Python 3 (they use asyncio). I'd like to be able to run flake8 with both versions of Python, while excluding the asyncio-specific tests for Python 2. I also have a list of other files and directories that I'd like both interpreters to exclude.

The config and cmd line options appear to be total overrides, and the only solution I've found so far is to have the exclusions listed out on the command line, with different lists for the two Python versions.

Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Greg